# where should i put server side code for google sites?

Tags: android

I'm developing an app from which I post some data to my webpage. From my android app, I send a request using http POST. This is my site : https://sites.google.com/site/aycsdk/advertisement

I'm following the tutorial at http://webhole.net/2011/11/15/android-tutorial-how-to-post-data-from-an-android-app-to-a-website/. My problem is, where should I paste the server-side code for my site so it can receive data from the app?

Answer (score 1):

Google Sites does not support server side PHP scripts as required by the post you referred to. Consider a hosting solution that allows PHP.

Also take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4577661/1321873

Comment: thanks for reply !! i visited this site for google app i have register domain for some dollars ? right ? i have to show in my app that data is sending from my app to different sites what i have to do for that ?? i know the domain name for that i also need server side sode for that site ?? can u plzz suggest something ?

Comment: can anyone suggest me something ?? i'll be very thankful badly stuck at this point

Comment: @Ashu, it is not quite clear what you want to achieve. If you can clearly state your requirements, we might be able to help you.

Comment: my task is to post ads on different sites for my app i have the client side code which communicate to the sites through Http POST request i dont know anything about server side code how to access it ? where should i add the server side code ?

Comment: When you say you want to post ads - do you have control on these sites? If you want to post to sites that you do not have control or administrative access, you need to know how the site expects the ad request and what parameters it expects. You cannot write some generic stuff and expect it to work on every site. There is no common language that everyone understands.