# can you have "variables" in text in google sites?

Tags: google-sites

Sorry, this is a bad question. I don't even know what the title should be. I'm a total noob at making websites so this might be easy to find but I just don't know the terminology to search for. I cannot find anything about how to do this...

What I want to do is have something like references/variables that I can use in a block of text and it will automatically get replaced with whatever value should be there. Best way I can think of to describe it would be if I was using the site as a design doc for a game or something, I would be able to type in [Title] or something similar on any page and when it loads that text would be replaced with whatever my Title is. That way If I ever change titles, names, classes, races, places, items, etc... they would only have to be changed in 1 place and the change would be reflected everywhere.

I notice if I add a link to a page it will automatically use the Title of that page as the text of the link. That is almost exactly what I want. Except when I change the Title of the other page the text of the link remains as the original text. It doesn't get updated to the new Title and that is not at all what I want.

Also, I want to do this in Google Sites and as simply as possible. I don't really want to use a database. I was hoping Google Sites would have some kind of funcionality for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible (on Google Sites) and likely you need to consider a hosted solution.

Quoting the answer from [this relevant post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577435/is-web-development-possible-using-google-sites):

> You should consider hosting your solution using Google's App Engine
>   instead of Google Sites. You can set it up so it uses PHP (see link
>   below), you can configure it to use your domain name and you get
>   enough CPU, disk and bandwidth allowance to serve around five million
>   page views for free each month, if you are serving more than that,
>   their prices are extremely competitive.
>
> Google App Engine:
>   http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/whatisgoogleappengine.html How
>   to setup PHP using Google App Engine: http://blog.caucho.com/?p=187

Also I'm not sure how your PHP skills are but if you're unfamiliar with it [then this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp) should help to get you started.

Comment: Where it lists subpages it is doing exactly what I'm looking for. All subpages are listed with a link to the page and the text of the link is automatically changed to the title of the page. The built-in subpages list can do it but there's no way to do it anywhere else?